# How to find all solutions of the optic equation $\frac{1}a+\frac{1}b = \frac{1}c$

Tags: diophantine-equations

[Optic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optic_equation#cite_note-Dickson-1) says for

$${\frac  {1}{a}}+{\frac  {1}{b}}={\frac  {1}{c}}$$

> All solutions in integers $a, b, c$ are given in terms of positive integer parameters $m, n, k$ by
>
> $$a=km(m+n) , \quad  b=kn(m+n), \quad c=kmn$$
>
> where $m$ and $n$ are coprime.

How is this proved? I went through [the reference](https://archive.org/details/historyoftheoryo02dickuoft/page/688/mode/2up), which says "A. Palmström, J. Sadier, and C. Moreau" "Ibid, 299-302". No clue what that means though.

Does anyone know how why all the solutions are covered by these formulas?

Comment: *Ibid.* is short for *ibidem*, Latin for "in the same place" (that is, same reference as previous line).

Comment: I looked at the references, it appears that this is the correct reference for that result:  Dickson, L. E., History of the Theory of Numbers, Volume II: Diophantine Analysis, Chelsea Publ. Co., 1952, pp. 688–691.

Comment: @Théophile Ah that means it's *L'Intermédiaire des math., 2, 1895*, won't be in English though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $$\frac 1a+\frac 1b=\frac 1
c$$ is equivalent to $$(a+b)c=ab\quad \text {or}\quad (a-c)(b-c)=c^2$$

Note that $(ka,kb,kc)$ is a solution iff $(a,b,c)$ is, so we may assume that $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$.

If $p$ is any prime dividing $c$ then $p$ must divide either $a-c$ or $b-c$.  It can't divide both, else $p$ would divide $\gcd(a,b,c)$.  Thus $p^2$ divides one of $(a-c),(b-c)$.   It follows that both $(a-c)$ and $(b-c)$ are perfect squares, so we may write, e.g., $(a-c)=m^2,\,(b-c)=n^2$.  Then, of course, $c=mn$.

Thus every relatively prime solution is given by $$a=m^2+mn=m(m+n)\quad \quad b=n^2+mn=n(m+n)\quad \quad c=mn$$

as desired.

Comment: Do you mean $(b - c) = n^2$. Would just edit it myself but not enough rep.

Comment: @simonzack  Yes, thank you.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

If there were no limits on the right side, then it would be

$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{a+b}{ab}$.

Because of the limits on the right side, the denominator has to be divisible by $a+b$, thats why one multiplies this to the denominators. This would be enough, but for saying that $m$ and $n$ are coprime, its necessary to multiply the denominators by k.